# Proper use of + in regex (R stringr)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

This seems like a basic question but I couldn't figure it out after spending a good part of the morning researching.

I want to understand **why** using `stringr::str_match()` in R

`NP_[0-9][.0-9]+` **or** `NP_[0-9]+[.0-9]{2}`

**and not** `NP_[0-9]+[.0-9]` **or** `NP_[0-9]+[.0-9]{1}`

matches `NP_848713.1` in

```
string1<-c("It_is_burried_in_here_NP_848713.1_somewhere")
```

**Thanks**

Comment: See how these regex patterns work at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com).

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks for the input. Duhhh, It counts the `.`. Now I feel a little stupid. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, the point is that `[.0-9]` matches 1 char and it is equal to `[.0-9]{1}` (the `{1}` is always redundant).

Comment: For some strange reason the `.` was not a character in my mind. A bad faux pas that send me spinning in all the wrong directions. Good on you to point out the redundancy of {1}.